# Webforms with subheadings that have their own fields

Tags: 7, webforms

I realise what field sets are as they can group parts of your webform together. What I am looking for though is to have subheadings within those fieldsets.

I've been trying to find tutorials about this but all I can find is tutorials on how to build a simple webform with just a title, description and then label-field pairs.

**Edit:** Say I want a form that calculates taxes for someone and I want to start off with a fieldset that has a couple of radiobuttons like male/female, I live rural/I live in the city and whatnot. Then I want some label/textfield pairs like name address phone, etc...
Then within the same fieldset I would have a title that says 'do you have a secondary address?' and have that be the title for a subset of fields with again address and zipcode, etc..

Comment: Do you want to have a fieldset with a title, description _and_ a subheading?

Comment: Yes but description is not even the issue here. I'll do an edit with an example.

Comment: Can't you use a nested fieldset for that? (Or am I still not getting it?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I got away with just putting up a markup title. I thought it was really necessary to have field groups in order to make a valid web form since it was suggested to me. I guess like Andy said, nested fieldsets might have worked as well.